# what is the difference between fglrx & Ati official drivers?

Tags: drivers, ati, xorg, fglrx

What is the difference between [this](http://www.securethelock.com/2014/04/20/installing-configuring-amdati-drivers-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr/) driver & [this](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux%20x86_64)? Are both same but first placed in repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AMD Catalyst drivers are called fglrx on Linux.

But depending on your graphics card and the task you want to do you might not need them as the Xserver drivers are fine too.

Comment: I need for HD videos & gaming by the way, which method should I go for? `Additional Drivers->fglrx` OR 1st method in question OR 2nd (Manually install)?

Comment: before installing do I have to remove default Xorg driver?

Comment: I'd prefer to install the fglrx via software center. You maybe have to activate the propetarian driver option -- not sure how this is called nowadays still on an older version.

Comment: do I have remove my default Xorg driver?

Comment: Don't think so -- but cannot say. Please open a new question for this maybe.